# How to run a computationally intensive class in a subprocess in Python multiprocessing and access it through the main process?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I currently have two classes, one is a class in PyQt and the other is a class for a geometry engine (computational intensive). If I put them both in the main process, the geometry engine would cause the QT interface to be unresponsive. So I want to separate them into two processes, one responsible for displaying the interface and the other responsible for computing. The PyQt interface needs to call functions from the geometry engine class, so they need to communicate.

I am trying to write a library that allows code to be migrated to a child process without modification, but the data transfer overhead is too large and I encountered the problem TypeError: cannot pickle 'SwigPyObject' object. I am thinking of a better solution.

I think the subprocess should maintain a message queue, but I'm not sure how to implement this specifically.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html and the paragraph headed "Exchanging objects between processes"

Comment: Can you explain a bit more which information need to be exchanged?

Comment: What does the geometry engine look like (it helps us to help you when you post code)? One approach is to either turn your "geometry engine" into a custom *managed* class or create a managed class that delegates to the geometry engine. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=basemanager#managers).

Comment: sorry - a bit more of code, preferably in the form of a minimal, reproducible, example is needed so that it is easy to answer this question.  (a minimal app with a single qt widget which shows up the "unresponsiveness" when putting everything in the same process, for example).

Otherwise an answer here won't be better what is thoroughly documented in the multiprocessing Python docs.

Comment: @Booboo @RaJa @jsbueno Thanks for your replies. The geometry engine is [pythonOCC](https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-core). I have written a [demo](https://github.com/ovo-Tim/multiprocessing-mq)， but I met `TypeError: cannot pickle 'SwigPyObject' object`

Comment: I also found a demo of [pythonocc](https://github.com/tpaviot/pythonocc-demos/blob/256079d3104dfbb1f7f9fe244bdbd66c916739ef/examples/core_parallel_slicer.py)

Comment: If the geometry engine is native code, you should be able to use threads too, so you don't need to pickle things to go down a multiprocessing IPC pipe.

Comment: @AKX This is assuming that the geometry engine releases the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). But looking at the code, it appears to be all Python.

Comment: It could still help (somewhat) with the unresponsiveness. That said, pretty sure it's not all Python since Swig is being mentioned.